# Excel formula for golf scores

Tags: worksheet-function

I am trying to keep a modified golf handicap for my group. We will use an average of the 6 lowest scores from a group of 15 scores. I need a formula that will look at 15 cells and pick out the lowest score, the 2nd lowest, etc for a total of 6. I can them sum and divide those 6 cells.

Comment: That worked great!!.

Comment: If my answer worked for you them please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list you can put 1 through 6 in a column and then refer to that column with SMALL to get the relative scores:

```
=SMALL($A$2:$A$16,C2)
```

With a simple `=AVERAGE(D2:D7)` to get the average.

[image]

---

If all you want is the average and not the list you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(A2:A16,ROW(1:6)))/6
```

Which will iterate 1 to 6 in the Small returning each answer and summing the group together.  Then is a simple division by `6` to get the average.

[image]